# Finding the last active thread to print something

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread class that's suppose to read a text file and count the number of words in the textfile.  The run call is as followed :

```
/**
 * Executes and counts # of words in textfile
 */
public void run()
{
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try
    {
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            String tmp = in.next();
            character ++;
            totalCharacter++;   
        }
        System.out.println(input + ": " + character);
        /**
        if(Thread.activeCount() == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Total characters in all textfiles: " + totalCharacter);
        }
        */
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }

}
```

I can't figure out how I can find the last Running Thread so that I can print out the total number of characters from every text file that is called. I tried to do it with the commented section Thread.activeCount()== 0 but that didn't work.

Any advice on what/where to find the last running thread to print out the total amount of words in all textfiles?

The main function would look like this(I am using commandline arguments to enter the information in):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++)
    {
        Thread2 wct = new Thread(args[i]);
        wct.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `Thread.activeCount` should be 1 as the current thread is still running?

Comment: i've played with the activeCount function for and neither 1 or 0 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small program:

```
package ant.test;

import java.util.Random;

public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private int msec;

    public ThreadTest(int msec) {
        this.msec = msec;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            new Thread(new ThreadTest(r.nextInt(1000))).start();
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread.activeCount = " + Thread.activeCount() + " activeThead = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(msec);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread.activeCount(exiting) = " + Thread.activeCount() + " activeThead = " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if(Thread.activeCount() == 2) {
            Thread[] tarray = new Thread[5];
            int nThreads = Thread.enumerate(tarray);
            for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
                System.out.println(tarray[i].getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is that, when the last thread is executed the number of active threads is two. The current thread and DestroyJavaVM Thread. See the output below:

```
Thread.activeCount = 4 activeThead = 8
Thread.activeCount = 4 activeThead = 9
Thread.activeCount = 5 activeThead = 10
Thread.activeCount = 6 activeThead = 11
Thread.activeCount = 6 activeThead = 12
Thread.activeCount(exiting) = 6 activeThead = 8
Thread.activeCount(exiting) = 5 activeThead = 11
Thread.activeCount(exiting) = 4 activeThead = 12
Thread.activeCount(exiting) = 3 activeThead = 10
Thread.activeCount(exiting) = 2 activeThead = 9
Thread-1
DestroyJavaVM
```

That said, checking the `activeThreadCount` doesn't seem to me the right solution. You may want to use some sort of counting semaphore for achieving what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the thread id to keep track of the various threads you create in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++) {
        Thread2 wct = new Thread(args[i]);
        wct.start();
        System.out.println("Thread #" + i + " has id " + wct.getId());
    }
}
```

The `System.out` statement I added will let you correlate the number of the thread with its running id, for later comparison if you want that.

And then in your thread `run()` method, you can also print out the id of the currently running thread right before the thread has finished executing:

```
public void run() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            String tmp = in.next();
            character ++;
            totalCharacter++;   
        }
        System.out.println(input + ": " + character);
    }
    finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
        long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
        // print out id of this Thread
        System.out.println("Thread with id " + threadId + " is about to finish executing");
    }
}
```

Comment: i've been playing with this idea; however, how am i suppose to do stuff with the last thread after i've ID it.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution is Based on CountDownLatch :

```
  Class myRunnable implements Runnable
 {
     CountDownLatch cdl;

     public myRunnable(CountDownLatch cd1)
     {
      this.cd1 = cd1;
     }

     public void run()
     {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        try
        {
           // Your code logic

            cdl.countDown();

            if(cd1.getCount() == 0)
                System.out.println("Total characters in all textfiles: " + totalCharacter);                
        }
        finally
            lock.readLock().unlock();
     }
  }

 Class Demo
 {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(10);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        Thread2 wct = new Thread(new myRunnable(cd1));
        wct.start();
    }
     cd1.await();
  }
}
```